# Generate layout histogram with specified parent values

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am new to D3, so my project of D3 is a rough problem to me and I really do need some help, I have been search solutions for days.

The problem is, I want to draw a Hierarchical Bar Chart, every time one clicks a bar, the sub layout of that bar is shown, just like this one  http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663, however, the value of parent node is the sum value of its children node. I want to set the parent value by myself and keep the layout. The json file is:

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "analytics",
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [
                {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
            ]
        },
```

I want to edit the parent value, so I edit the file as :

```
{
    "name": "flare",
    "children": [
    {
        "name": "analytics",size:555555 //I want to set value by myself rather than the sum of children value
        "children": [
        {
            "name": "cluster",
            "children": [
                {"name": "AgglomerativeCluster", "size": 3938},
                {"name": "CommunityStructure", "size": 3812},
                {"name": "HierarchicalCluster", "size": 6714},
                {"name": "MergeEdge", "size": 743}
            ]
    },
```

However, it does not work. Does anyone knows how to set parent's value? I searched for days and got nothing, hope you can help me, and I am appreciate your help!

Answer (score 0):

Is your issue with using the parent element sizes to draw the bars? If so, you should scale everything (to say 0 to 100) and then multiply this by a constant to get the appropriate parent value. After all, if you edit each parent value, they won't necessarily be proportional.

Here's an example of a scale:

**edit: (fixed the domain)**

```
var myscale = d3.scale.linear()
                .domain([0, maxParentWidth])
                .range([0,y]);   // .range([0,1]) is the default range
```

This will scale all the "parents" on the domain 0 to the largest parent value to a range of [0,y], where y is whatever you want (i.e., 100). Let's say you want the largest parent bar to be `300px`. Now, all you have to do is multiply this scaled value by a constant, in this case, 3.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the answer, you are right, but I also want the scale size dynamically changes when the children elements showed. This is the situation I got right now: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1283663 ,I want to set the parent's x axis bar as 100 %, and do the same to children's x axis, right now the maximum of value of parent is 45000 which is the sum of children's...am I clear.. I am very appreciate your answer!!!

Comment: Okay, so if you want the scale to change when you click a child element (so that the transition leaves the largest child at 100%), then make another scale with a domain of [0, largest child width] and a range of [0,100] or [0,1] (the latter is the default).

Comment: Here's an explanation of scaling in d3: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-linear_domain

Comment: Thank you very much, I spend days try to find a solution. I will try you method:)